# Compare and complete two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to compare an array with a array model and complete the structure, like this example:

```
array = [0,1,2,3,4]
model = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

result = [0,1,2,3,4,0,0]
```

The model can't be changed, it's a reference array.

Any ideas about the best way to achieve this?

Comment: what is the ground for comparison? larger, smaller, equal?

Comment: @MongZhu for what I understand is different from zero

Comment: define best. Fastest? less code possible? ...

Comment: Don't forget about `Enumerable.Zip` eg. `array.Zip(model, (f, s) => f-s);`

Comment: @CallbackKid That will iterate to the shorter of the two sequences, so it would not include the trailing zeros for the example.

Comment: @jurharr, I realize that, I was just putting in my two cents, since the OP put such a little amount of information about what he needed. Otherwise I would have posted it as an answer.

Comment: @CallbackKid Then even as a comment you should have at least pointed that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the short one into the long one:

```
int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] model = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };


int[] result = model;

array.CopyTo(result, 0);

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", result));
```

If best means fastest as you wrote in your comment then here is a comparison:

```
Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();

int[] array = new int[10000];
int[] model = new int[10200];

st.Start();
var asdf = array.Concat(model.Skip(array.Length)).ToArray();
st.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Concat: " + st.ElapsedMilliseconds);


int[] arraya = new int[10000];
int[]  modela = new int[10200];

st.Restart();
int[] result = modela;
arraya.CopyTo(result, 0);
st.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Copy: " + st.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that like that:

```
var array = new[]{0,1,2,3,4};
var model = new[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

var result = array.Concat(model.Skip(array.Length)).ToArray();
```

This will concat the missing elements from `model` at the end of `array`.

---

[`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat), [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) and [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray) are LINQ extension methods declared in the `Enumerable` class in namespace `System.Linq`. So you need to add `using System.Linq;` to your code.

Comment: I get the message "System.Array don't have a definition for 'Concat'", i forget any reference?

Comment: @user3571412 yes, they are LINQ extensions. Add `using System.Linq;`. Updated my answer.

Comment: This won't be the fastest.

Comment: @MatthewWhited That is surely true, but I can't see that performance was an issue for OP. There even may be contradicting criterias like "with least memory usage" or "with the shortest code". I only start micro-optimization if it's necessary.

Comment: @user3571412 I just now read your comment below your question that it's actually the _fastest_ you are looking for. So there are definitly faster answers here. Please remember to add those requirements to your question next time :)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the array lengths upfront you can do this...

```
int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] model = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };

Array.Copy(array, model, array.Length);
```

if not you can so something like this...

```
int[] model = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var array = new int[7];

var shorter = array.Length < model.Length ? array : model;
var longer = array.Length >= model.Length ? array : model;
Array.Copy(shorter, longer, shorter.Length);
```

... fastest without mutation of originals ...

```
int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] model = { 4,5,6,7,8,9,1, };

var x = array.Length < model.Length ?
    new { s = array, l = model, sl = array.Length, ll = model.Length } :
    new { s = model, l = array, sl = model.Length, ll = array.Length };

var result = new int[x.ll];

Array.Copy(x.s, result, x.sl);
Array.Copy(x.l, x.sl, result, x.sl, x.ll - x.sl);
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants his `model` to be changed during the operation.

Comment: This is what I'd do if it's just to copy to a bigger array.

Comment: then declare a new array and copy both in.. `Array.Copy` is pretty much the fastest option you have other than an unrolled loop.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my version... Might be a bit faster than LINQ. My assumption is you're replacing based on array with larger number but I may be wrong.

```
var array = new[]{0,1,2,3,4};
var model = new[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{    
    if(array[i] > model[i])
    {
        model[i] = array[i];
    }
}
```

If not you can simply do an Array.Copy

Comment: If you want fastest you will need to move the `array.Length` check before the loop.

Comment: Uh, I'm actually assuming the user already knows their array structure.

Comment: yes, but this will call `array.Length` on each pass.  do `var len = array.Length; for(var i = 0; i<len;i++))` will be faster.

Comment: Wow! I doubt this will have any performance significance, I've come across this before... any benchmark links?

Comment: for 7 elements in debug... maybe.

Comment: That answer is not correct.  If will look correct in debug but if you change to release it will show fast improvement on my example (assuming a large dataset)  At this small the improvement is so tiny it's not really worth considering.

Comment: I agree with his cache explanation, and in addition, Marc Gravell can't be wrong at the same time. "there is a scenario where the JIT does something clever here; with arrays it spots the common < arr.Length case and bypasses some length overrun tests". – Marc Gravell♦ Jul 30 '10 at 8:41

Comment: If you do any more than the extermely simple example (such as access a second array to get the value to store in the first array) the cache will be lost and the loop will be slower.